# python aiohttp-sse timesout after exactly 6 requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, server-sent-events, aiohttp

I am writing an sse server in python 3.6 with aiohttp-sse. However, whenever I make exactly six sse requests to the server, the server timesout all further connections (I just see a constant 'pending' on Google Chrome). Note, no errors are produced. Here is my code:

```
import asyncio
import json
import aiohttp
from aiohttp_sse import sse_response
from aiohttp.web import Application, Response

async def subscribe(request):
    print('new sub')
    async with sse_response(request) as resp:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await resp.send('hello')

        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        await resp.send('hello')

        await asyncio.sleep(8)
        await resp.send('hello')


    return resp


async def static_page(request):
    return Response(text = open('static_page.html', 'r').read(), content_type = 'text/html')


# grab asyncio eventloop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# instantiate app
app = Application(loop = loop)

app.router.add_route('GET', '/sub', subscribe)
app.router.add_route('GET', '/', static_page)


# startup
aiohttp.web.run_app(app, host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8080)
```

I added the print statement in the subscribe function that prints 'new sub.' After six connections, this print statement is not even run. Thus, I know that the subscribe function is not called after six sse connections. I think this might be a problem with aiohttp config. Does anyone know anything else about this?

Another thing I noted was that when the timeouts started occurring after the six sse connections, static pages wouldn't work either — I would also get a timeout when trying to load them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [browser limit for HTTP connections with the same domain name](https://docs.pushtechnology.com/cloud/latest/manual/html/designguide/solution/support/connection_limitations.html).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)